# Can't read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, undefined

I've been getting an error along the lines of "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" and the error traces back to *this* code

```js
const roleName = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => (r.name === args[1].toString()) || (r.id === args[1].toString().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')));
```

What's going wrong here?

slightly larger peice of code

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return message.channel.send(`You do not have MANAGE_ROLES permission`)
try {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    const member = message.guild.member(user);
    const roleName = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => (r.name === args[1].toString()) || (r.id === args[1].toString().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')));
    //after this i create a discord embed, give the member the role specified then send the embed.
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: try const roleName = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r && (r.name === args[1].toString()) || (r.id === args[1].toString().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')));

Comment: returns the same error

Answer (score 0):

Add an Elvis operator:

```
const roleName = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => 
  (r?.name === args[1].toString()) 
  || (r?.id === args[1].toString().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''))
);
```

Or do it the old way:

```
const roleName = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => 
  r 
  && (r.name === args[1].toString()) 
  || (r.id === args[1].toString().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''))
);
```

Comment: I just found out that it was never this statement it was the fact that i put an extra space where it didnt belong -,-

Answer (score 0):

So you're getting this error because you're trying to access 'r.name' in your Array.find() method and some of the entries in the array appear to be 'undefined' or 'null'. I would first run an Array.filter(r => !!r) and then chain on the .find() method afterwards to make sure all your entries are not undefined/null.

Comment: yeah i had an extra space in my input and since i was copy/pasting the message i was sending it kep doing the same thing.... turns out after mentioning a user it automatically puts a space, i never noticed this... :/